# CancellationToken not working C#

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, task, cancellationtokensource

I am trying to learn cancellation token and i created one simple windows form application to apply it. But the cancel button does not create any cancellation request. I have two buttons, One for GetRequest and another cancel button and one await method. button1 is for GetRequest and button2 is for Cancel
Below is the sample code.  Thanks for the help.

```
CancellationTokenSource tokenSource; // I have this one the top of the class
```

Async Method

```
private async Task CountPrime(int start, int count)
    {
        tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        button2.Enabled = true;
        button1.Enabled = false;
        try
        {
            var result = await Task.Run(() =>
            Enumerable.Range(start, count).Count(x =>
            Enumerable.Range(start, (int)Math.Sqrt(x) - 1).All(y => x % y > 0)), tokenSource.Token);
            MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Cancelled");
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Exception");
        }

        finally
        {
            button1.Enabled = true;
            button2.Enabled = false;
        }

    }
```

Here is the code for button1 ( Get Request)

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        await CountPrime(2, 3000000);
    }
```

and Finally I have cancel button

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tokenSource.Cancel();
        button2.Enabled = false;
    }
```

Comment: And exactly what did you expect to happen?

Comment: When i press the cancel button, i want to cancel the program request by giving the cancellation message. in this case, i want to catch OperationCanceledException message.

Comment: @user3280146 then do so - your code *doesn't* check the token. It *doesn't* use it anywhere. It's not that it isn't working, you aren't using it

Comment: @user3280146 I suggest you check the docs, especially [Cancellation in Managed Threads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Task Cancellation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396(v=vs.110).aspx) to see how cancellation tokens work. In cooperative cancellation the *worker* checks the token and cancels its work in an appropriate manner.

Comment: I have used cancellation token (  tokenSource) in async method and i am using the same tokenSource.cancel() in Cancel Button.

Comment: @user3280146 - maybe so, but you don't have anything calling `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` nor checking `IsCancellationRequested` on the token.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I was missing token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); in CountPrime Method.